# HTML and webView

Tags: ios, image, uiwebview

i am using a webView to display the data, which comes from the server in a string like that:

```
<div><img src="/app/public/images/news/2014/02/28/yan.JPG?rand=0.21853141812607646" style="width: 470px; height: 362px;" /><br />
<small class="muted pull-right">
```

And all is fine, but i want my WebView to scroll only vertically. So i want to resize the images. What should i do? 
 First thought - i should replace `style="width: 470px; height: 362px;"` like `style="width: 320px; height: 362px;"`  to fit my webView, but it doesn't work.

That's how i load my webView: `[self.web loadHTMLString:fullHTML baseURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sostav.ru"]];`

Comment: You could try adjusting the UIWebView settings instead... I think it has an `aspect fill` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Checked Your link: "http://sostav.ru/app/public/images/news/2014/02/28/yan.JPG?rand=0.21853141812607646". and i come to the following points:

1. You have to add the below settings in your UIViewController Class where you initialize your UIWebView.

   ```
   - webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
   - webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
   - webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   - webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   - webView.opaque = NO;
   ```

   after the above changes you Horizontal Scrolling will stopped. and now all of your link will be adjusted in iPhone Screen width.

Comment: thanks, i think it is equal to "scales page to fit" option in Interface Builder. But the text is too small that way. I should better talk to their developers. I think the should give me the mobile content.

Comment: ok. if you like my way of answers than dont forget to upvote me. thanks :)